# Using a single method to add items to different jComboxes

Tags: java, swing, oop, methods

```
public void getUnit(){

 String cat1;

 try{

  String sql="Select unit from unit";

  pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);         

rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next()){

  cat1=rs.getString("unit");


  jComboBox6.addItem(cat1);

 }}

catch (SQLException ex) {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

  }}
```

Comment: are you trying to loop through a set of ComboBoxes?

Comment: no i want this method to add items to a different combobox, here in this method this adds item to jCombobox6.

Comment: Please explain what' your problem in your question, as is, it's unclear what you're asking, and please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want this method to add items to a different combobox,

So don't hardcode the combo box. Instead you pass a parameter to the method.

So you change the method signature:

```
//public void getUnit()
public void getUnit(JComboBox theComboBox)
```

and change the code in the method to use the parameter:

```
//jComboBox6.addItem(cat1);
theComboBox.addItem(cat1);
```